# Raise an alert in rails controller without redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, controller

I just want to flash an notice/error if the message is/isn't saved, without any redirect, how can I have no redirect:

```
  respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save
    format.html { redirect_to request.referer, :notice => 'Message sent!' } #dont want redirect
  else
    # error message here
  end
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `flash.now`:

```
if @message.save
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Message sent!'
else
  flash.now[:alert] = 'Error while sending message!'
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { # blahblah render }
end
```

Comment: @RahulDess probably too late, but for everyone else: yes it does work in Rails 4. It's even mentioned in the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now

Answer (score 2):

In rails 5, you can do:

```
format.html { redirect_to request.referer, alert: 'Message sent!' }
```

Comment: This raised `too few arguments` for me

Comment: You need to wrap it in respond_to.

 `respond_to do |format|
 format.html { redirect_to request.referer, alert: 'Message sent!' }
end`